# How to install missing libssl.so.1.1 in docker?

Tags: docker, openssl

There are lots of problems asked about libssl but seems no one matches mine, so I raised a new question.

I'm trying to deploy my python api project on docker, but when I created the container and run it, it exited automatically. By executing `docker logs container_id`, it displayed such an error: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I understand that this problem is gonna happen, as the current docker directory doesn't contain those files. So I tried to fix it by adding this into the dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get libssl-dev
```

But when I tried again, still the same error occurred, seems it is not installed, as I tried `CMD find / -name libssl.so.1.1`, I got nothing in the log.

The system is Ubuntu 22.04 and my complete dockerfile is as listed:

```py
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Comments are provided throughout this file to help you get started.
# If you need more help, visit the Dockerfile reference guide at
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim-buster as base

# Prevents Python from writing pyc files.
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Keeps Python from buffering stdout and stderr to avoid situations where
# the application crashes without emitting any logs due to buffering.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Copy the project into the container
COPY . /

# Install pipenv
RUN pip install pipenv

#
RUN pipenv run python3 -m pip install paddlepaddle-gpu==2.5.1.post102 -f https://www.paddlepaddle.org.cn/whl/linux/cudnnin/stable.html

# Install missing openssl dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get libssl-dev
# Install dependencies
RUN pipenv install --verbose --pypi-mirror https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple

# Expose the port that the application listen on
EXPOSE 5000

# Run the application
CMD find / -name libssl.so.1.1
```

except from what I listed above, I make no other attempts to solve this problem.

Comment: Your docker file has libssl.dev and not libssl-dev ?  Also, should it not be apt-get install libssl-dev ?

Comment: sorry for the mistake, I've edited it, it was libssl-dev that I run.

Comment: `slim-buster`? That's not Ubuntu but Debian. This should be posted on [unix.se] instead.